# How do I fix this type error ('value' must be an instance of str or bytes, not a float) on Python

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

I want to plot a graph for Covid-19 in India and so far there's no problem when I manually input my data as x and y axis. But since the data is quite long and when I want to read it as .csv file, it gives me this error *'value' must be an instance of str or bytes, not a float*. I have also try to wrap *int(corona_case)*, but giving me another new error, *cannot convert the series to <class 'int'*. Also I would be very appreciate if someone can suggest me tutorials on plotting graph involving datetime using python since this is my first time learning python.
I am using Python 3.

p/s I seem can't find a way to share my csv file so I am gonna leave it in snippet.

```html
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates as mpl_dates
import numpy as np

plt.style.use('seaborn')

data = pd.read_csv('india.csv')
corona_date = data['Date']
corona_case = data['Case']
 
plt.plot_date (corona_date, corona_case, linestyle='solid')

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

plt.title('COVID-19 in India')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Cumulative Case')

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

```html
Date,Case
2020-09-30,6225763
2020-10-01,6312584
2020-10-02,6394068
2020-10-03,6473544
2020-10-04,6549373
2020-10-05,6623815
2020-10-06,6685082
```

Comment: can you share a CSV file with us?

Comment: have you tried the astype method? int(corona_case) won't work because you are trying to convert a pandas series to int. That is not what you want to do as your goal is, that every value in the series is of type int. Have a look at the documentation I would assume this solves the problem. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html

Comment: data.astype({'Case': 'int32'})

Comment: Your code works fine with the snippet you provided. Must be something wrong with the complete file?

Comment: @jmandt I have tried astype method too. But this time it gives me this error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2020-01-30'.` I have also format my date but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

convert all DataFrame columns to the int64 dtype

```
df = df.astype(int)
```

convert column "a" to int64 dtype and "b" to complex type

```
`df = df.astype({"a": int, "b": complex})`
```

convert Series to float16 type

```
s = s.astype(np.float16)
```

convert Series to Python strings

```
s = s.astype(str)
```

convert Series to categorical type - see docs for more details

```
s = s.astype('category')
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't give further information but this might work:

```
corona_date = (data['Date']).astype(str)
corona_case = (data['Case']).astype(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the type of column in pandas dataframe like this.

```
corona_case = data['case'].astype(int) # or str for string
```

If that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi, I have seen and tried this one too before, this too, would give me an error, ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\t'

Comment: that means there are non number characters in the case column in this case a tab('\t'). You can try removing these characters. `pd.to_numeric(data['case'], error='coerce')` which converts number values in string to numbers and non-numeric values to null then remove null values `data.dropna(subset=['case'])`.

Comment: I've tried that, but still giving me a value error. I think there must be something wrong with my column date, as I put non number characters *2020-01-30* ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2020-01-30'.

Comment: I have also add these 2 lines, but still giving me the same error. `date_format = mpl_dates.DateFormatter('%b, %d, %Y')`
`plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_format)`

Comment: Pandas reads datetime in string format from csv. You can convert it to datetime as `data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])` and that works with matplotlib. It would be better if you can share the csv.